unity error CS1061 newbie gamedev tutorial not working Vector2 doesn't contain def for input
I am using a tutorial by Natty gamedev and encountered this issue in the first tutorial am using newest recommended version of unity
I am also new to gamedev and unity in general
the exact error message is
Assets/Scripts/PlayerMotor.cs(26,33): error CS1061: 'Vector2' does not contain a definition for 't' and no accessible extension method 't' accepting a first argument of type 'Vector2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
my code is as follows am using a youtube tutorial
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController Controller;
    private Vector3 PlayerVelocity;
    public float speed = 5f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    //recieve the inputs for our InputManager.cs and apply them to out character controller.
    public void ProcessMove(Vector2 input)
    {
        Vector3 MoveDirection = Vector3.zero;
        MoveDirection.x = input.x;
        MoveDirection.z = input.t;
        Controller.Move(transform.TransformDirection(MoveDirection) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}


and my second script is
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput PlayerInput;
    private PlayerInput.OnFootActions OnFoot;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
       PlayerInput = new PlayerInput();
       OnFoot = PlayerInput.OnFoot;
       motor = GetComponent<PlayerMotor>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        //tell the playermotor to move using the value from our movement action.
        motor.ProcessMove(Onfoot.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>()); 
    }
    private void OnEnable() 
    {
        OnFoot.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable() 
    {
       OnFoot.Disable();
    }
}


the error comes from the first script but maybe second one is also needed to fix error
i tried looking if i have any spelling mistakes
i also tried searching online couldn't find anything
maybe the tutorial is outdated

MoveDirection.z = input.t;. Is this a typo?
